How to write query for multi-column sorting in Laravel/Livewire?
I want to add multi-column sorting feature in my data table made with Laravel and Livewire. I will receive an array of column names and sort direction from frontend and I have to order the query based on the received array.
Array example:
$sortColumns = [
    'status' => 'asc',
    'company' => 'asc',
    'salary_group' => 'desc',
    'name' => 'asc',
    ................
    ................
];

How do I perform the query on my model to chain these sorting of columns?
*** Edit: Also I want to paginate the query.
I have tried to chain orderBy on my query but the number of sorting columns in the array is not fixed. So I don't know how to chain indefinite number of orderBy.

You could simply iterate over your Array and call ->orderBy():
$sortColumns = [
    'status' => 'asc',
    'company' => 'asc',
    'salary_group' => 'desc',
    'name' => 'asc',
    ................
    ................
];

$query = Model::query();

foreach ($sortColumns as $column => $order) {
  $query->orderBy($column, $order);
}

// Any other query logic

$result = $query->get();


How do i do this with pagination? @tim-lwis

->paginate() instead of ->get()

You may also leverage laravel collection methods for immutability:
    $sortColumns = [
        'status' => 'asc',
        'company' => 'asc',
        'salary_group' => 'desc',
        'name' => 'asc',
    ];

   $query = collect($sortColumns)
       ->reduce(function ($query, $direction, $column) {
           return $query->orderBy($column, $direction);
       }, Model::query()
    );

   $results = $query->get();

